# Number formatting DIV

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, number-formatting

I am trying to number format a numerical value that is dynamically inserted into a div via a custom field in wordpress. I cant use `<?php echo number_format('100000000') ?>` because the number changes all the time and there are thousands of posts, so cant edit each one with a custom field, I tried using:

`<?php echo number_format('get_post_meta($post->ID, "Displayed Price", true)') ?>`

but that didn't work and just shows an error... I would like a simple string of code that will tell whatever number is in a div called "price" to be thousand formatted/separated

any suggestions? please help :)

Comment: try : echo number_format(get_post_meta($post->ID, "Displayed Price", true)) -- the single quotes are making it a string.

Comment: Formatted how? There are different ways to format numbers, depending on language. Do you want code that has a single way (which?) hard-wired or code that adapts to cultural conventions (based on what?)?